# css fixed div moves on first tap on ipad

Tags: css, ipad, position, fixed

I have the following CSS rule for `div` element in my webpage

```
#menudiv {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    background: transparent;
    z-index:3;
    min-height: 680px;
}
```

This is a menu on the left on my page, and it's fixed positioned. It works well on normal PC displays, while on iPad there is an issue.

When I load the page and I touch the screen with the finger scrolling down, the `#menudiv` moves together the rest of the page. When I release the finger, the `#menudiv` returns to its fixed position and then I can scroll up and down the page and it's no longer moves. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `left` property. Also if possible then use top, right, bottom also(as its fixed div)

```
#menudiv {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    left: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    z-index:3;
    min-height: 680px;
}
```

Comment: Tried with left instead of margin-left, no luck :(

Comment: @user3106475 Please try top/bottom also

Comment: Tried 'top:0' and 'bottom:0', since the menu is full height, nothing changed.

Comment: New: added a solid border to #menudiv, it seems work. However I don't know why, and I don't want to see a border there.

Comment: @user3106475 then you can use border with transparent color. I have added border in my answer.